# Apache Wicket - How to retrieve the selected value from DropdownChoice in java

Tags: java, html, wicket, dropdownchoice

Java class :                                                                            This is the method where i created the dropdownchoice object for select menu and add it to the form. In this method adding the projects list to the billableProjectsList

```
public class ReportCriteria implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = xxxxxxxxxL;
   
    private ReportCriteria selectedBillableProject;


    public ReportCriteria getSelectedBillableProject() {
        return selectedBillableProject;
    }

    public void setSelectedBillableProject(ReportCriteria selectedBillableProject) {
        this.selectedBillableProject = selectedBillableProject;
    }
}

private Form<ReportCriteria> createCriteriaPanel(String id, 
                                         IModel<ReportCriteria> model) {
  SelectionForm form = new SelectionForm(id, model);
  ReportCriteria criteria = (ReportCriteria) getDefaultModelObject();
  List<Project> billableProjects = ProjectUtil.filterBillable(allProjects);
  IModel<Project> dropdownModel =   new 
                    PropertyModel<Project(criteria,"selectedBillableProject");
  DropDownChoice<Project> billableProjectsList = new DropDownChoice<>(
                    "projectsList",
                    dropdownModel,
                    billableProjects,
                    new ChoiceRenderer<Project>("fullNameWithCustomer"));
   billableProjectsList.setLabel(new ResourceModel("printMonth.billable"));
   form.add(billableProjectsList);
   System.out.println("selectedBillableProject --- >"
                                  +billableProjectsList.getModelObject()
                                  +"value is --->"
                                  +criteria.getSelectedBillableProject());
    }
```

Html file code :  This html file is for select menu display .

```
<td style="padding-left: 5px">
   <strong>
       <wicket:message key="printMonth.billable"/>
   </strong><br/>
   <p style="border-top: solid 1px white;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:0">
      <select wicket:id="projectsList"></select>
    </p>
</td>
```

Error : This error is resulted once i select the dropdown value from the list . I have created the variable selectedBillableObject in ReportCriteria class and have added the setter and getter.
But i am unable to convert it in this method to add it to form since it is type casting issue . But when i tried to print the value in selectedBillablePorject , its is null .

```
<pre>11-19@16:52:50 ERROR org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper - Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at 
[SelectionForm [Component id = criteriaForm]] on component [SelectionForm [Component id = criteriaForm]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:236)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:890)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.util.convert.ConversionException: Could not convert value: net.rrm.ehour.domain.Project[----] to type: net.rrm.ehour.report.criteria.ReportCriteria. Could not find compatible converter.
    at org.apache.wicket.ConverterLocator$DefaultConverter.convertToObject(ConverterLocator.java:121)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolverConverter.convert(PropertyResolverConverter.java:95)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:1194)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver$ObjectAndGetSetter.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:651)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:151)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.setObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:132)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:3052)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.setModelObject(FormComponent.java:1577)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1098)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:230)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:200)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:274)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:262)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrder(Visits.java:245)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.visitComponentsPostOrder(FormComponent.java:424)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.internalUpdateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1860)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.updateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1825)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:955)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:788)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:721)
    ... 52 more
11-19@16:53:18 ERROR org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper - Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onFormSubmitted of interface org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.IFormSubmitListener targeted at [SelectionForm [Component id = criteriaForm]] on component [SelectionForm [Component id = criteriaForm]] threw an exception
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:216)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:243)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:236)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:890)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1484)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.apache.wicket.util.convert.ConversionException: Could not convert value: net.rrm.ehour.domain.Project@328849ff[]] to type: net.rrm.ehour.report.criteria.ReportCriteria. 
ould not find compatible converter.
    at org.apache.wicket.ConverterLocator$DefaultConverter.convertToObject(ConverterLocator.java:121)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolverConverter.convert(PropertyResolverConverter.java:95)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver$MethodGetAndSet.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:1194)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver$ObjectAndGetSetter.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:651)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.util.lang.PropertyResolver.setValue(PropertyResolver.java:151)
    at org.apache.wicket.model.AbstractPropertyModel.setObject(AbstractPropertyModel.java:132)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.setDefaultModelObject(Component.java:3052)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.setModelObject(FormComponent.java:1577)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.updateModel(FormComponent.java:1098)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:230)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form$FormModelUpdateVisitor.component(Form.java:200)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:274)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrderHelper(Visits.java:262)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.visit.Visits.visitPostOrder(Visits.java:245)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.FormComponent.visitComponentsPostOrder(FormComponent.java:424)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.internalUpdateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1860)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.updateFormComponentModels(Form.java:1825)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.process(Form.java:955)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:788)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onFormSubmitted(Form.java:721)
    ... 52 more
    </pre>
```

Comment: Was finally able to retrieve the selected value by retrieving the billableProjectList.getModelObject() and setting it to criteria.setSelectedBillableProject().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is

```
 new PropertyModel<Test>(this," ");
```

?

PropertyModel is used to read/write object's member fields. I am pretty sure Java syntax does not allow to name a member field as " ", i.e. a space character.

In addition the method that you should use is dropDownChoice.getModelObject(), not `getObject()`.

**Update**:

```
public class ReportCriteria implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = xxxxxxxxxL;

private ReportCriteria selectedBillableProject;
```

`selectedBillableProject` has to be a `Project`, not `ReportCriteria`.

Comment: Also the ChoiceRenderer looks a bit odd as it's typed with 'Items', while its DropDownChoice uses 'Test' as type.

Comment: I added the line -new PropertyModel<Test>(this," "); --  to set the default value as empty string in dropdown. Is it not the right way ?

Comment: I even tried to retrieve the dropdownchoice.getModelObject() - but it didnt show the value nor can be added to Form sincei get typecasting error

Comment: Test selectedItem= billableItemsList .getModelObject(); - when i try to retrieve this , i receive  java.lang.ClassCastException:

Comment: @martin-g     , i updated the code as "IModel<Test> dropdownModel =   new PropertyModel<Test>(this,"selectedBillableItem ");"    . Also defined the variable with the setters and getters for  selectedBillableItem . But it is resulting in error as " org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception in rendering component: [DropDownChoice [Component id = itemsList]]  Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method defined for class: selectedBillableItem

Comment: Please update the code in the question so we can see what is not correct.

Comment: Please provide the whole stacktrace of the new error.

Comment: We are almost there - please share the code of ReportCriteria.

Comment: martin-g - i updated the selectedBillableProject to Project and rerun the applciation . But the below code is providing null value :System.out.println("selectedBillableProject ----->"+billableProjectsList.getModelObject()+"value is --->"+criteria.getSelectedBillableProject()); console displayed as 
 selectedBillableProject ----->nullvalue is --->null

Comment: 1. Check browser's DevTools Network tab to see what value is being submit; 2) Override Form#onError() and put a breakpoint to see whether it is called. It is a good practice to update a FeedbackPanel with error/success messages

Comment: martin-g , i realised that the line of code "System.out.println("selectedBillableProject ----->"+billableProjectsList.getModelObject()+"value is --->"+criteria.getSelectedBillableProject());" runs when the form is loaded , so the default value is empty hence it shows null . Hence i tried to set the value to the feild property , but unable to add to the form due to type cast issue . criteria.setSelectedBillableProject(billableProjectsList.getModelObject()); Any suggestions on  the same .

Comment: martin-g - since have a seperate function as OnSubmit , where i want to retrieve the selected value , but without adding to the form i will not be able to use the same

Comment: @martin-g Thanks alot it worked finally .  Updated the resolution

Answer (score 2):

Lest go by parts:

1.- Why are you trying to use a property model to handle DropBox selected option?
You are defining a Property Model like this:

```
IModel<Test> dropdownModel =   new PropertyModel<Test>(this," ");
```

Property Model is used to tied the fields of yout POJO with the model object, doing the
"binging" between your POJO's and Wicket componentes automitically. In your sintax
`this` should be a model object that handles a POJO, and instead of `" "` you
should put the name of the property of the POJO that will be tied to that Property
Model. Maybe this is the reason of why you are getting *"No get Method defined* because
`this` doesnt have a POJO with a property called `"selectedBillableItem"`, remember,
Property Models use 'getters' and 'setters' for seeking the POJO's properties.

2.- I have used DropDownChoice as follows:

```
DropDownChoice myDropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice<String>("myDropDownChoiceWicketId", new Model<String>(), List<String> object);
```

3.- Recovering the selected item of DropDownChoice as follows:

```
anyModelObject.getObject().setToAnyProperty(myDropDownChoice.getModelObject());
```

Hoping you get any hints from this.

Comment: - i updated the code as you said to : IModel<Test> dropdownModel =   new PropertyModel<Test>(getDefaultModel(),"selectedBillableItem"); since the getDeafultModel() is already in use for some other dropdownchoice object .  I have also defined the setter and getter for selectedBillableItem. But still it results in Caused by: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: No get method defined for class: class selectedBillableItem

Comment: -  i could fix the error by the following code - IModel<Test> dropdownModel =   new PropertyModel<Test>(criteria,"selectedBillableItem"); it is displaying the dropdown values and not showing the earlier get method exception . Since i created the property in POJO class - criteria for selectedBillableItem

Comment: But when i try to print the value of selected object using - billableItemsList.getModelObject() - it is null even though i change the value . Shows the error - Caused by: org.apache.wicket.util.convert.ConversionException: Could not convert value:

Comment: Verify what kind of object are you receiving from 'billableItemsList.getModelObject()' after change the value.

Starting from your first approach, you can try:

'IModel<Project> projectModel = new Model();

DropDownChoice<Project> dropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice<Project>("dropdownId", projectModel ,lisTestModel');

dropDownChoice.getObjectModel();'

Comment: after i changed the code to IModel<Project> projectModel = new Model(); , their is no error . But when i evaluate the expression billableProjectsList.getModelObject() - it is null value